# Include a tex file that contains the bibliography section

Tags: natbib, include, paths

I found when I tried to keep the spaces in my file name by using `\include{{""}}`, then the file could still be included, but the references would be question marks.

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sort, authoryear, round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{document}

\include{{"Sections/The study plan"}}

\bibliography{References.bib}
\end{document}
```

The file /Sections/The study plan.tex

```
\section{The study plan}
\citep{abc}
```

The file /References.bib

```
 @Article{abc,
  Title                    = {{adc}},
  Author                   = {Adams, D. W. and Errington, J. },
  Journal                  = {Nat. Rev },
  Year                     = {2003},

  Month                    = {Sep},
  Number                   = {9},
  Pages                    = {64--65},
  Volume                   = {7}
}
```

If I delete the spaces in my file name, and use `\include{}`, it works fine.
For example, if I rename `\Sections\The study plan.tex` as `\Sections\Thestudyplan.tex` and use `\include{Sections/Thestudyplan}`, the reference will show up fine.

I know you might say "just delete the spaces", or "use `input` instead" etc etc, but I wonder if there is way to keep the spaces in the file names and still use `include`. Thanks!

Comment: I'd say you can try `\include{"Sections/The study plan"}` (no double braces), but my advice is, as you predicted, *don't use space in file names*.

Comment: Of course I tried `\include{"Sections/The study plan"}`. This way the `include` wouldn't work at all, not just the natbib.

Comment: What might be the reason for preferring `\include` over `\input`? Incidentally, it should be `\bibliography{References}`, not `\bibliography{References.bib}`, i.e, you should omit the `.bib` extension.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your posting, as the issue you're encountering isn't linked directly to the natbib package.

Comment: @Mico, `\include` allows to include/leave out e.g. a section or chapter, and process the rest (considering the labels/citations in it, even if it isn't typeset). Not very relevant with today's fast machines...

Comment: @vonbrand - The same holds for `\input`, doesn't it?

Comment: @Mico, no. `\include` starts a new page, `\input` doesn't. `\include`s can be managed with includeonly (unsure about exact syntax, sorry), no control over `\input` available.

Comment: @vonbrand - We have no information from the OP as to (a) whether a page break at the start of the section is even desired or (b) whether he/she is using `\includeonly` to manage which file(s) should be included in a given compilation run. My view is that unless there's a good reason for using a more complicated instrument, I think it's wise to use the simpler instrument. (Of course, the whole matter would be moot if the OP weren't using spaces in the file name(s).)

Answer (score 1):

I can see no compelling reason for using `\include` in the setup you describe. The `\input` instruction seems to be tailor-made for just the case at hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort, authoryear, round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{document}
\input "Sections/The study plan"
\bibliography{References} % NOT "References.bib", i.e., omit ".bib"
\end{document}
```